# Take Avg value as a 0 when Divide it by zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two database fields(SQL Server) those fields are decimal. Both of those fields are 0 in SQL Query I need to take percentage of those values. In this record shows Error on database. But if this happens I need to show 0 value.

> > There's a scenario  TotalSalesPrice = 0.00 & CurrNewsPrice= 0
> >     Then the Avgnews formular is AvgNews = (CurrNewsPrice / TotalSalesPrice) * 100

```
Select  TotalSalesPrice,CurrNewsPrice,CAST(CurrNewsPrice AS decimal(18,2)) / CAST(TotalSalesPrice AS decimal(18,2)) * 100.00 AS AvgNews
from [dbo].[N_NewsLine]
```

Answer (score 4):

special case it?

```
select  TotalSalesPrice,CurrNewsPrice, case
    when TotalSalesPrice = 0 and CurrNewsPrice = 0 then 0
    else CAST(CurrNewsPrice AS decimal(18,2)) /
          CAST(TotalSalesPrice AS decimal(18,2)) * 100.00
    end AS AvgNews
from [dbo].[N_NewsLine]
```

Comment: I think the case option is far more readable / clearly showing the logic intention personally

Comment: Can i limit Margin value to 2 decimal places?

Comment: @TechGuy you can do anything you want... just add the logic that you want - all the mathematical and type conversion operations are available to you

Answer (score 3):

use `NULLIF()` on the denominator. And `ISNULL()` on the result of the calculation

```
Select TotalSalesPrice,
       CurrNewsPrice,
       ISNULL(CAST(CurrNewsPrice AS decimal(18,2)) 
            / CAST(NULLIF(TotalSalesPrice, 0) AS decimal(18,2)) * 100.00, 0) AS AvgNews
from [dbo].[N_NewsLine]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check it before using those values.

```
Select  TotalSalesPrice,CurrNewsPrice,IIF(TotalSalesPrice = 0, 
                                            0,
                                            CAST(CurrNewsPrice AS decimal(18,2)) / CAST(TotalSalesPrice AS decimal(18,2)) * 100.00)  AS AvgNews
from [dbo].[N_NewsLine]
```

Comment: Can i limit Margin value to 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

use case...when.. before the calculation

```
Select  TotalSalesPrice,CurrNewsPrice,
CAST( Case CAST(TotalSalesPrice AS decimal(18,2))
when 0 then 0.00
else CAST(CurrNewsPrice AS decimal(18,2)) / CAST(TotalSalesPrice AS decimal(18,2)) * 100.00 end AS decimal(18,2)) AS AvgNews
from [dbo].[N_NewsLine]
```

Comment: Can i limit Margin value to 2 decimal places?

Comment: @TechGuy surely that's exactly what the `CAST(TotalSalesPrice AS decimal(18,2))` does...

Comment: @MarcGravell AvgNews comes like 11500.0000000000000000

Comment: @TechGuy this is just a pre-judge before the division,you can do all number format you want

Comment: @TechGuy oh you're talking about in the *output*? tip: never ever worry about formatting your data in SQL; that's a job  for the code that *consumes* the data and renders it for output. It it was me, I wouldn't even do the `* 100.00` - heck, I might not even do the calculation in the SQL, since I'm already returning both columns required - all of these are *display* concerns, not data concerns; and SQL is 100% about data, and 0% about display

Comment: @TechGuy I modify the script ,you can test it and see the result

Answer (score 0):

Select  TotalSalesPrice,CurrNewsPrice,CAST(CurrNewsPrice AS decimal(18,2)) / CAST(NULLIF(TotalSalesPrice,0) AS decimal(18,2)) * 100.00 AS AvgNews
from [dbo].[N_NewsLine]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results to be `decimal(18, 2)` then do the `cast()` *after* the division.  The rules for the result type when dividing decimals is . . . rather Byzantine (no offense intended to Byzantines).

I would recommend `NULLIF()` to avoid the divide-by-zero, resulting in:

```
Select TotalSalesPrice, CurrNewsPrice,
       cast(CurrNewsPrice * 100.00 /
            nullif(TotalSalesPrice, 0) as decimal(18, 2)
           ) as AvgNews
from [dbo].[N_NewsLine]
```